# ESP32 with two power supplies (AC/DC + USB) using Schottky diodes

Tags: power-supply, mains, esp32, fuses, schottky

I'm building a small circuit to power an ESP32 with two different power supplies.
Normally the circuit will be powered from AC, using a [Mean Well IRM-02-5 AC-DC power supply](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/IRM-02/IRM-02-spec.pdf) to get 5VDC out of 220VAC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpiyUG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But sometimes the USB cable will be connected to the ESP32 (to upload firmware) at the same time the AC-DC power supply is on. This will result in two power supplies being connected to the ESP32.

My goal is to protect both sides from reverse current. To solve this I'm thinking in connecting two Schottky diodes. This has some logic? Will they protect both power sources from reverse current?

I've never used this type of AC-DC power supply like the IRM-02-5. Is ok to place only a fuse for protection or I need anything else in the 220V side?

Comment: What you show in your diagram should work just fine.

Comment: Ok great, thank you.